# How to implement a transition duration using D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

A text box should pop up upon `mouseenter`. It currently works, however there's no gradual transition, its instantaneous.
Here's my code so far:

```
let svgTarget = document.querySelector('svg #target' + newId);
let tr = d3.transition()
  .duration(5000)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear);

svgTarget.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (e) {
  d3.select('svg #tooltip' + newId)
  .transition(tr)
  .duration(8000)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .style("display", "inline");
},)
```

The `mouseenter` functionality works and displays the box but again it is instantaneous. Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add a listener, use [**selection**.on()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_on).

Like a lot of things in D3, event listeners act on selections:

```js
d3.select('svg #tooltip' + newId)
  .on('mouseenter', function() {
    d3.select(this) // this being the prior selection
      .transition(tr)
      .duration(8000)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .style("display", "inline");
    });
```